# Algebraic maps and morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

Let $X,Y$ be two projective varieties (irreducible). A map $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is called *continuos algebraic map* if its graph $\Gamma(f)\subseteq X\times Y$ is an algebraic set. I'm trying to check that there exists an open $U\subseteq X$, such that $f_{|U}$ is a morphism. Any help?

Comment: I do not think this is true in positive characteristics. In zero characteristic, since the projection morphism $\Gamma(f)\to X$ is bijective, there is a non-empty open subset $U\subset X$ where this map is an isomorphism. Rest, I hope is clear.

Comment: How can I check this in zero-charcateristic?

Comment: It depends on what theorems you know. If $f:X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism of varieties which is quasi-finite (fibers are finite), then there is a non-empty open set of $Y$ where the map is finite. If you have a finite map, in characteristic zero, there is a non-empty open set where the map is unramified. So, in your case, restricting to an open subset, you may assume the map is finite, unramified and bijective. Further restricting to a smaller open set, you may assume the base is normal. Then, it is immediate to check that the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: I don't know these results. Can you suggest me a reference for studying these theorems?

Comment: All standard texts will do these. The first result I quoted is usually called `generic finiteness' and the second, `generic etaleness'.

Comment: Many thanks! :)